# Linux - auto restarting with sleep

Tags: linux, while-loop, sh

Current code of mine is

```
while true; do ./program; done;
```

I don't have access to a linux box right now and only way to do my request will be made on the live server and I don't want to test and jeopardize something, so I would be happy if I could get some help

Is this the way it should be if I want my program to sleep 2 seconds after each restart?

```
while true; sleep(2); do ./program; done;
```

Comment: "I don't have access to a linux box right now": just install it in Hyper-V or VirtualBox, or install the app on Windows 10, takes you less than 30 minutes

Comment: Also, you could check using an innocuous command (e.g. `lis`).

Comment: I don't have a big harddrive tbh on this computer so I am limited in many ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost fine.

1. `sleep` is a program, so pass him the arguments as space-separated list.
2. logical test (i.e. `true`) should be followed immediately by `do`
3. If `sleep` is before `./program`, the latter is sleeped before, not after. You could consider reordering them.

`while true; do ./program; sleep 2; done;`

Comment: So basically if the server restarts and I use sleep 2 before ./program it won't sleep it for 2 seconds, it HAS to be after? and thanks for telling me it has to be after "do" I didnt know that

Comment: OK, so you want to delay starting of the program? Then sure, `sleep` goes first.

Comment: @edward - No, _sleep_ doesn't **have** _to be after "do"_ - if it's before, its status value is tested by `while`.

Comment: @Armali  Thanks for explaining the other syntax. Anyway, I don't think I have ever seen this in real code, for me it look a little obfuscated, :-)

Answer (score 1):

`do` keyword enters the loop. Write it before any command that you want to repeat.

```
while true; do
    sleep(2);
    ./program;
done
```

Comment: @edward - This advice is wrong; one cannot write `do` _before any command_, since `true` is a command as well. Moreover, the only error in the original question hasn't been corrected.

Comment: I edited the answer to be more explicit. Anyway I think it was clear enough for everyone that I was talking about the commands inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
while true; do
    ./program
    sleep 2
done
```

Comment: @edward Bartłomiej and me post answers simultaneously.